# Secure EuroDOCSIS 3.0 Cable Modem

Tags: memory, networking, security

Does there exists a EuroDOCSIS 3.0 cable modem, where the internal flash memory has write protection, so that the the configuration can't be changed during runtime if write protection is enabled?